# "with all" vs. "as well as"

Tags: phrase-usage

So I'm confused as to which of the following is correct:

> The chief, with all his men, was massacred.

or

> The chief, as well as his men, was massacred.

Comment: Both are correct. Btw, add "**all**" in the second sentence too.

Comment: Why do you think one is correct and one is incorrect?  Please add more detail to the question explaining what you find confusing, otherwise it may be closed.

Comment: @SovereignSun wouldnt the second be "were"?

Comment: @maxpleaner The verb agrees with singular "**chief**" as far as I remember.

Comment: Thank you, SovereignSun and Andrew! I was thinking the second sentence was correct while the first one was incorrect...because the 'all' in the first sectenced seemed out of place to me, while the 'as well as' in the second sentence seemed more appropriate to me. My friend said first is correct; I said second is correct. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are fine.  "The chief and all of his men" are a compound subject would take a plural verb.  Or you could say "The chief and all of his men were massacred" or "The chief was massacred along with all of his men."  These are both a single subject with a singular verb, but they just happen to have an additional phrase to add further information.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are correct, stating the fact that the chief and his men died,but there may be a slight nuance between the two

> The chief, **with** all *(of)* his men, was massacred.

Might be understood to mean, the chief was with his men when they were all killed, whereas

> The chief, as well as *(all of)* his men, was massacred.

Might be understood that the chief was *some place else*, for example held prisoner away from his men, when he was killed.